# How to update the android keystore Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak) to a strong key

Tags: android, rsa, sha1, android-security

How to update the android keystore Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak) to a strong key

```
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak)
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 1024-bit RSA key (weak)
Version: 3

Warning:
The certificate uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.
The certificate uses a 1024-bit RSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.
```

Answer (score 5):

As the warning indicates, there are two problems. It is not possible to "update an **algorithm** ... to a strong **key**".

> The certificate uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.

This is because the collision resistance of SHA-1 has been [SHAttered](https://shattered.io/). Use signatures with SHA-256 (`"SHA256withRSA"`) or SHA-512 (`"SHA512withRSA"`) to counter this. You could also take a look into PSS signtures, although the PKCS#1 v1.5 signature format that "SHA256withRSA" implements is still considered secure.

> The certificate uses a 1024-bit RSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.

To have a 128 bit security it is necessary to upgrade to 3072 bit RSA key pairs. This means regeneration of the key pair and probably requesting a new certificate as well. 2048 bit RSA keys are still in common use, but I would only use this minimum key size for backwards compatibility reasons (or, indeed, if larger key sizes are not feasible for either you or your CA).

Comment: If I create a new key, I can't able to update the existing apps. Are you mentioning there is no way to update the existing key? I have converted to PKCS12 using the keytool command. Still it shows the error as weak key in the google play console. Could you let me know about the PSS signature for android. Note: While checking the signing repost I got SHA256 shall I use this or any other workarounds?

Comment: "If I create a new key, I can't able to update the existing apps." I guess you need an update strategy. Aiming for cryptographic agility is a goal that gets more and more attention. Changing the key store obviously doesn't do anything to the stored key or the algorithms you use it for. As for PSS: try [this maybe](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec#example:-rsa-key-pair-for-signingverification-using-rsa-pss)?

Comment: I think I need to add the Keygenerator PSS with produce a key. But while generating the build I think I need to use the existing keystore. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that comment. Uh, yes, AndroidKeyStore can be enhanced to include the signature generation algorithm it seems. I'm not sure what "generating the build" means, but you should certainly be able to use the same key store.

Comment: Okay. So after adding the PSS, I can use the same keystore to generate the aab.

Comment: That should be *logical*; however, I'd recommend you try to find out, I haven't tested myself. API's and implementations are not always that logical.

Comment: I have tried the PSS: try this maybe link and the example available in my code. Not sure how can I verify this by bundling the aab. Still facing the weak error in the google play console. Also I have added the key1 as the aliasName.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240321/discussion-between-sejn-and-maarten-bodewes).

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: The solutions in the answer are valid. If there are implementation issues then please create a new question with the full context. Maybe @sejn can be pushed to post some updated code for the key pair generation for the Android key store but otherwise I'd say: implement the solution in the answer & test it for your target platforms.